# Executing 'sed' through 'spawn' into a expect script

Tags: linux, ssh, expect

I am writing a simple **expect script** for accessing to a remote server without introducing the password with the command window.

I am able to access to the remote server, and there I want to modify a text file. This modification is performed with the '**sed**' command for finding a 'keyword', the line where this 'keyword' is located is deleted.

The part of the code that is giving me **problems** is the combination of '**spawn**' with '**sed**' is the following one

```
spawn sed -i -e '/keyword_to_delete/d' /home/my_file
```

Since this is doing in a expec file I have to do it through 'spawn' command. I switch on the debug info mode and the main error info in the screen is :

```
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "exit\r\nsed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''\r\n"
cannot interact with self - set spawn_id to a spawned process
```

I hope I have show the problem here clear and in a nice way, if not tell me and I will try to do it better.

Thanks so much

CODE:

```
 set ip [lindex $argv 0]

 set port [lindex $argv 1]

 set password <PSWD>


proc sendPass {} {

global ip
global port
global password

spawn "/usr/bin/ssh" -X -p $port root\@$ip "-o StrictHostKeyChecking no" "-o UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null"

while {1} {
  expect {
    "IN"                     {break}
    "Are you sure you want"     {send "yes\r"}
    "assword"                   {send "$password\r"}
  }
}

spawn chmod 775 /etc/hosts
spawn sed -i -e {/operator/d} /etc/hosts
spawn sed -i -e {/default/d} /etc/hosts

send "exit\r"
expect eof

}; # end proc sendPass

#execute proc
sendPass


# script itself terminates
interact
```

And the current error is : "sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc//sedDEb2Fx: Permission denied"

Comment: Could you try to use double quotes instead of single ones?

Comment: Then the error turns into --> expect: set expect_out(buffer) "sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc//sedcrTA8t: Permission denied\r\n"

Comment: That means that you don't have permissions to create a temporary file under /etc.

Comment: I'm not sure how sed creates the temp filename, but what is the value of your TEMP environment variable?

Comment: Can you post the rest of the script?  There's not really enough context here.

Comment: Here is all the code, and the error now is : "sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc//sed05CzHz: Permission denied"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Again I'm not an expert of `expect`, but your script looks to swawn `chmod` and `sed` on your **local** machine, not on your remote machine.  Shouldn't you use `send chmod 775 ...` instead, just like you're using `send exit` to execute `exit` on your remote machine?
2. [This is how `sed -i ...` works](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/%5Bjava%5D-how-to-append-something-to-each-line-in-a-text-file-719325/#post3509906).  You will notice that you need a write permission on `/etc` where a temp file will be created.  To avoid it you need to explicitly create a temp file by not using `-i`, eg. `sed -e /foo/d /etc/hosts > /tmp/hosts; mv /tmp/hosts /etc`.  Maybe you need `cp` instead of `mv`, but I'm not sure... I'm too lazy to try `strace mv ...` by myself.

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes have no special meaning to Tcl (here are the things that [do have special meaning](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)), so you want

```
spawn sed -i -e {/keyword_to_delete/d} /home/my_file
```

Comment: Then, the error is the following: "sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc//sedDEb2Fx: Permission denied" ; I want to delete lines in a txt placed in '/etc' of the remote server...

Comment: This is the best answer for using sed with spawn.. Thanx alot

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm not very familar with `expect(1)` since I directly use SSH for such kinds of tasks:

```
ssh user@remote_server "sed -i -e '/keyword/d' /home/my_file"
```

If you really need to use `expect` with telnet or something, how about this: save the sed script in somewhere in your `remote_server`, like `/usr/local/bin/del_kw.sh`, and then execute it by expect.  I think this is more manageable way to solve your problem.  Are there any reasons you cannot use this approach, eg. because your system is mounted on a read-only rootfs?